# grouping selections on multiple possible values in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite3 db where a table contains information on tests run, such as:
table A
name status  time

---

testa passed  33
testb failed  22
testa failed  41
testc passed  18
testa passed  27

some of the tests get renamed from time to time, such as testa to testa1, and possibly later testa1 to testa2. So my table could end up looking like:
table A
name status  time

---

testa passed  33
testb failed  22
testa1 failed  41
testc passed  18
testa passed  27
testa2 failed 45

I can keep track of the changes in a separate table like:

Table B
name   alias

---

testa  testa1
testa  testa2

although I'm undecided on the second entry being 'testa testa2' or 'testa1 testa2', whether one might work better than the other (ideally either one would work). I want to be able to group them somehow, so my query would combine the aliases, so my result would look something like:

testa, testa1, testa2: 2 passed 2 failed
testb: 0 passed, 1 failed
testc: 1 passed 0 failed

So I'd need two steps in the query, one to group testa, testa1 and testa2 and include the sum of the results for that group with the results for the (not renamed) test. I can get the grouping done (as long as I don't have more than two aliases) with:

select a.name, a.alias as name1, (select b.alias from B b where a.name = b.name and b.alias != a.alias limit 1) as name2 from B a group by a.name;

where B is the alias table but I can't figure out how to combine that with the others:
select name, alias from A left join B on job_table.name = B.name where name not in (select alias from B) group by name, alias;

but this gives me the aliases in pairs (testa testa1 on one line, testa testa2 on the next) and doesn't help me with summing those totals.

Comment: Is `name` in Table B always the original name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.name, a.name) || COALESCE(',' || GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.alias), '') test,
       SUM(a.status = 'passed') passed,
       SUM(a.status = 'failed') failed
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b
ON b.alias = a.name
GROUP BY COALESCE(b.name, a.name)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6bc4dc5c89d137dd117fb9aa1a64aef8).
Results:

| test | passed | failed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| testa,testa1,testa2 | 2 | 2 |
| testb | 0 | 1 |
| testc | 1 | 0 |

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me. It might be because I only have access to sqlite 3.14.1, but I pasted all that code into my shell and ended up with:sqlite> SELECT COALESCE(b.name, a.name) || COALESCE(',' || GROUP_CONCAT(b.alias), '') test,
   ...>        SUM(a.status = 'passed') passed,
   ...>        SUM(a.status = 'failed') failed
   ...> FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b
   ...> ON b.alias = a.name
   ...> GROUP BY COALESCE(b.name, a.name);
testa  4  0
testa1  0  2
testa2  0  2
testb  0  2
testc  2  0

Comment: sorry, formatting trouble above, but you got "testa, testa1, testa2 2 2" and I got "testa 4 0" on one line followed by "testa1 0 2" and then "testa2 0 2"

Comment: @Tim the code in my answer would run fine in version 3.14.1. If you get the results that you posted in your comment then your data is not what you posted in your question. Create a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 with your actual data, so I can test.

Comment: sorry, it's working now. Something was off when I pasted it into my unix window I guess.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7de85a0e137bfefe767b104e8a9b5243 so I took your example and changed one "testa" to "testa1" and I get multiple instances of testa1 in the answer.

Comment: @Tim I added DISTINCT inside GROUP_CONCAT(). See my edited answer and:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4dbe16c561e57a689a797912ca62e2b1

Comment: much better, thanks. Knew it needed a distinct, wasn't familiar enough with coalesce to figure out where.